# First Time VBA Delete Rows Based on multiple Criteria

Tags: vba

Every day I get a report with ten thousand lines.

One of the columns has only two values, I would like to select one of them and delete the rest.

Another Column has more then 50 values, from which I need 5, and again I would like to delete the rest of the rows that do not match the 5 values on that column.

I have used autofilter and try to delete all filtered out rows, but it simply takes to long.

Can anybody give some light?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Super User! Sharing your research helps everyone. [Edit] your question and tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask].

Answer (score -1):

if I were in your shoes, I would try to remove those rows with knowledge I've gained while using Windows 10 "This PC".

In "This PC":

- While holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> you can click on different items to select multiple items (to keep, in this example).
- Then after releasing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> I could press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> and then <kbd>s</kbd> followed by <kbd>i</kbd> to run "Invert Selection".
- Then to delete all those unneeded files I could press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>.

**So, I would suggest trying to select multiple rows while holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, in VBA, and then search the VBA menus for something like "Invert Selection".**

**And since it seems you are using something like Excel, I would try clicking on the spot before the start of a row to select the entire row.** *Sorry, I don't know if you already know this.*

---

Note: I've never used VBA, but maybe this could help. :)